# Pass data from QML WorkerScript.sendMessage call through message signal

Tags: qml

I want to create a QML WorkerScript object dynamically and read the output from its function in my JavaScript code. Here's what I'm trying in my QML file:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    id: root
    width: 200
    height: 300

    Component.onCompleted: {
        var worker = Qt.createQmlObject('import QtQuick 2.0; WorkerScript { source: "dataloader.js"; }', root)
        worker.sendMessage();
        worker.message.connect(function (msg) { console.log(msg); });
    }
}
```

And here's the source of the dataloader.js file:

```
WorkerScript.onMessage = function(msg) {
    WorkerScript.sendMessage('test');
}
```

I would like the code to output "test" to the console but it outputs "QVariant(QQmlV4Handle)" instead. I see in some examples on the Qt site (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-workerscript.html and http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-threading-example.html#workerscript) that there is a messageObject property but that doesn't seem to be accessible from the connect function when I try to access it with worker.messageObject. Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why it works this way but I got the functionality I wanted by catching the message signal in the WorkerScript object and emitting the messageObject to a new signal that I added to the object. Here's a code sample (dataloader.js stays the same):

```
var worker = Qt.createQmlObject('import QtQuick 2.0; 
    WorkerScript { 
        signal loaded(var value); 
        source: "dataloader.js"; 
        onMessage: { loaded(messageObject); } 
    }', root)
worker.loaded.connect(function (value) { console.log(value); });
worker.sendMessage();
```